# Spelling mistake in country name when exporting as PDF

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, spelling, export

When looking at the plain HTML version of my careers CV the country shows up as "United Kingdom" as expected, however when I click the create PDF link the country name becomes "Unkited Kingdom". This is also the spelling in the generated PDF file.

Comment: I sure wouldn't want to live in a kingdom without kites!

Comment: Can't reproduce. I am getting "United Kingdom" on the PDF.

Comment: Could be a localization issue; different translation string set for different language locale?